# Metal Material with MeshStandardMaterial in three.js

Tags: three.js, rendering

From what I know it should be possible to use MeshStandardMaterial to define metal-like-materials in Three.js which should follow a pbr-roughness-metalness-workflow but I cannot find any good examples on how to accomplish that.

I cannot use Phong-Shader, I have to stick to MeshStandardMaterial.

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap.html

Comment: Thats actually the answer to my question. Is it somehow possible to mark this comment as an answer?

Comment: No, but I posted one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use `MeshStandardMaterial` to represent a metal-like material. Be sure to specify an environment map -- especially for metals.

```
material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {

    color: 0xffffff,

    roughness: roughness,
    metalness: metalness,

    roughnessMap: roughnessMap,
    metalnessMap: metalnessMap,

    envMap: envMap, // important -- especially for metals!
    envMapIntensity: envMapIntensity

} );
```

See the [three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_displacementmap.html).

three.js r.84

Comment: Thank you, Environment Map makes the difference. Great!

Comment: Does this apply for ```MeshLambertMaterial``` too?